# Set ng-model of input type text, on the basis of multiple record and a condition

Tags: angularjs, typescript

```
json = [ 
 question-list:{
   question-Text: "the car more than 25 years old",
   answer-list:[
    {answerDisplayText: "58",answered:true},         
    {answerDisplayText: "", answered:false}]
   }
]
```

so i want fill the input text box with `"answerDisplayText"`  using the `ng-repeat` if answered is `true` in answer list else will be blank.

Comment: use ng-if read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: show us what you have tried?

Comment: There are multiple entries in answer-list. Are there text-inputs for each one of them? Didnt get your question completely

Comment: <div ng-repeat="q in question-list.answer-List">
                    <input  type="text"
                           ng-model="q.answerDisplayText"
                           class="form-control"
                           ng-blur="ctrl.fillAnswerAndQuestionQuestionnaireid(ques.qustnnreQustnId,q.answerDisplayText,ques.saveRequired,event);" />
                </div>

Comment: @curil i used ng-if but in case of false input box don't populate , Answered may be FALSE in both list, So if answered is false then input box should be blank.

Comment: There Should be one input box. and value should be from answer-list. if Answered is true then value should be of "AnswerDisplaytext" corresponding to Answered true else false.

Answer (score 0):

> if answered is true in answer list else will be blank.

Based on your input data :

```
{answerDisplayText: "58",answered:true},         
{answerDisplayText: "", answered:false}
```

If you just bind to `answerDisplayText` it should work out just fine anyways :)

Comment: Can we concat answerDisplaytext  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-if and check if there is no answers for a given question. If there is not show a seperate div, with an empty input. See example below.

```js
angular
  .module('exampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController);

function ExampleController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.jsonObject = [{
    questionText: "the car more than 25 years old",
    answerList: [{
      answerDisplayText: "58",
      answered: true
    }, {
      answerDisplayText: "",
      answered: false
    }]
  }, {
    questionText: "this question has none answered",
    answerList: [{
      answerDisplayText: "58",
      answered: false
    }, {
      answerDisplayText: "",
      answered: false
    }]
  }];
  vm.isHavingAnswer = function(answerList) {
    var isHavingAnswer = false;
    angular.forEach(answerList, function(answer) {
      if (answer.answered) {
        isHavingAnswer = true;
      }
    });
    return isHavingAnswer;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='exampleApp'>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
  <div ng-repeat="questionList in vm.jsonObject">
    <p>Question: {{questionList.questionText}}</p>
    <div ng-if="answer.answered " ng-repeat="answer in questionList.answerList">
      <label>
        Answer:
        <input type="text" ng-model="answer.answerDisplayText">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!vm.isHavingAnswer(questionList.answerList)">
      <label>
        Answer:
        <input type="text" ng-model="questionList.answerList.newAnswer">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @basarat  In that case two input box will show. A question should have only one text box

Comment: I have updated the example, but I don't really understand what it is you are trying to do. Can you please let me know if the above example is what you are after and if it is not then please let me know some scenarios and what you want the output to be, e.g. what should happen when two answers are true.

Comment: U concated value from javascript side. i wanted to add all anserDisplayText with in ng-repeat..by the way..my Requirement is clear i want to show answer from the list if answered is given then fill that answer in text box else show empty

Comment: I have updated the example again. I believe that what you want to do is bind the true answer or if there is no answer that is true to show an input that is empty.

Comment: What is "newAnswer" ?  but as per code snippet by you what exactly i wanted.  I also resolved it in the same way you did but i added a new field in json out side the Answerlist and itreate the answerlist and saved is true then set value in new added field.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-hide="json.answered==false"><input type="text" ng-model="json.answerDisplayText"></div><div ng-hide="json.answered==true"><input type="text"></div>
```

Comment: two different text box will display. i need one text box to display the answer